# How to check whether given email address is invalid in action script 3?

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, email-validation

I need to check whether given email address is invalid in action script. Following is the code/regex i came up with.

```
private function isEmailInvalid(email:String):Boolean
            {
                var pattern:RegExp = /(\w|[_.\-])+@((\w|-)+\.)+\w{2,4}+/;
                var result:Object = pattern.exec(email);
                if(result == null) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
```

But it seems like above code do not cover all the test cases in the following link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/testing123/archive/2009/02/05/email-address-test-cases.aspx

Does anyone have better way of doing this?

Folowing are the tested valid emails i used (above function should return "false" for these):

```
firstname.lastname@domain.com 
firstname+lastname@domain.com 
email@domain.co.jp
```

Folowing are the invalid ones (so function should return "true" for these):

```
email@domain@domain.com
.email@domain.com
email..email@domain.com
plainaddress, email@domain..com
```

Comment: `\w{2,4}` is wrong for matching TLD. It matches `___` and doesn't match `museum`. Here is the official list of TLDs at this time: https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Comment: Don't use regex to validate email addresses.  They invariably exclude many perfectly valid email addresses, causing unnecessary frustration to your users.

Comment: like to know, what'll be the best way to validate email addresses other than using RegEx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `+` at the last and you must need to put anchors.

```
^(\w|[_.\-])+@((\w|-)+\.)+\w{2,4}$
```

Simplified one,

```
^[\w_.-]+@([\w-]+\.)+\w{2,4}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vT2aY9/1)

Comment: Thanks Avinash. Will give this a try and let u know.

Comment: @AvinashRaj But have you checked the link OP has given? it a long list. Am not sure how to match the entire

Comment: Seems like it returning "true" for both cases:

(email@domain.com) is invalid: true   |  
(plainaddress) is invalid: true

(tested email address is given inside the bracket)

Comment: post the tested email addresses in your question.

Comment: [Tested valid emails:   firstname.lastname@domain.com, firstname+lastname@domain.com, email@domain.co.jp ]  [Tested invalid emails:  email@domain@domain.com, .email@domain.com,  email..email@domain.com, plainaddress, email@domain..com]

Comment: Both of these expressions are wrong.  They will incorrectly mark many valid emails as "invalid".  See http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/  and http://regexr.com/39qmq for a demo

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegExp :

```
RegExp = /\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/;
```